# Cup product in the cohomology of the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let us consider cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is well known that \begin{align*} &H^0(T) = \mathbb{Q}\\ &H^1(T)=\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Q}\\ &H^2(T)=\mathbb{Q} \end{align*} in which $T=S^1\times S^1$ is the torus.

If we consider $u,v\in H^1(T)=\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}$ to be the two generators of this cohomology module, is there an easy way to see that $u\smile v \neq 0$ or $u\smile u\neq 0$ ?

Obs: $\smile$ is the usual cup product.

Comment: It depends on how you did the calculation and what you have for these generators. It follows pretty much immediately from knowing the cohomology of $S^1$ if you computed this using the Kunneth theorem.

Comment: do you know that the cup product is poincare dual to intersection when homology classes are represented by submanifolds? It's not too hard to see that the self intersection number of a generator is zero (just move $S^1 \times \{0\}$ over to $S^1 \times \{t\}$, these are homologous and intersect trivially.)

Comment: That's the happiest way to see it for me